# Connection refused - jaxws catalog in combination with jaxws-maven-plugin

Tags: java, web-services, maven, soap, wsdl

I'm trying to make my wsdl location not static anymore in my generated client (using the jaxws-maven-plugin), but I'm not having a lot of succes.

What I've found is the following..

My plugin (placed in the plugins in the build of the pom):

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>ecad-ws</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsimport</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceDestDir>${basedir}/target/generated-sources</sourceDestDir>
                        <keep>true</keep>
                        <verbose>true</verbose>
                        <extension>true</extension>
                        <wsdlDirectory>src/main/resources</wsdlDirectory>
                        <wsdlFiles>
                            <wsdlFile>CBS.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                        </wsdlFiles>
                        <wsdlLocation>http://localhost/wsdl/msw/cbs?wsdl</wsdlLocation>
                        <catalog>
                            ${basedir}/src/main/resources/META-INF/jax-ws-catalog.xml
                        </catalog>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

and a jax-ws-catalog file (placed in src/main/resources/META-INF):

```
<catalog xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:entity:xmlns:xml:catalog" prefer="system">
<system
    systemId="http://localhost/wsdl/msw/cbs?wsdl"
    uri="../CBS.wsdl" />
</catalog>
```

the CBS.wsdl is placed in src/main/resouces. As far as I understand my research the above code changes the URL in the generated client to http://localhost/wsdl/msw/cbs?wsdl (that's working) and then, when the client is invoked, it looks for the catalog and matches the above url to ../CBS.wsdl. That last part isn't working since I'm getting the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service.
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>(WSDLServiceFactory.java:94)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.initializePorts(ServiceImpl.java:204)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.<init>(ServiceImpl.java:148)
... 118 more
Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR:   Problem parsing 'http://localhost/wsdl/msw/cbs?wsdl'.: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.getDocument(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.loadDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:244)
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.getDefinition(WSDLManagerImpl.java:191)
at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.<init>(WSDLServiceFactory.java:92)
... 120 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

I can't really find another solution. If I'm not changing the wsdl location in the generated client I'm always getting something like "Failed to access the WSDL at: file: XXXXX" (what is completely normal)

I'm using the jdk 7 btw..

Answer (score 0):

This answer is about 6 years late, but...

I wandered onto this question as I was searching for how to setup the catalog file in my own repository .. in 2021 .. using Java 11. I managed to get it to work for my repo, and looking at this configuration above against mine, the only thing I could say is that you might need to add `${basedir}` to the `<wsdlDirectory>` section.

```
...
    <wsdlDirectory>${basedir}src/main/resources</wsdlDirectory>
...
```

I'm leaving this here for the next weary developer (like me) who has to implement a wsdl connection in the age of REST.